# When a proper noun is converted into a verb, should it be capitalized?

Tags: writing-style, capitalization, proper-nouns, verbing

If a proper noun (e.g. Google) is converted into a verb (e.g. Let me (G/g)oogle that for you), should it still be capitalized when used as a verb? I recognize that English has no such concept as a "proper verb," but writing a brand name like Google in lower case seems odd to me.

Comment: Not unless you want to capitalize it.

Comment: Google has stated that they want the verb to be capitalized. However, that hasn't stopped it from being used in lowercase by many people. It even has a [*dictionary entry*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/google) in lowercase.